# How can I disable auto-brightness on dell xps 9300 running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dell, brightness, xps

I tried using dconf-editor, but disable auto-brightness had no effect. If I shift my legs the laptop brightness changes. Its really annoying and should be turned off.

Comment: I think I had this problem too. The screen would randomly dim up and down constantly without any change in the amount of light in the room or anything else.

Comment: did you find a fix?